# How to emphasize adjectives?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice, adjective, semantics, emphasis

In English, and most modern European languages, we have one single word, "very," which is accepted as the regular way to make an adjective more extreme.
Is there a common way to do this in Latin?
Ways I can think of are just using the superlative, or using some adjective like *nimis*, *multum* or *magnopere*.

E.g. (something) is very cold: maybe *est frigidissimus*, *est multum frigidus* or *est nimis frigidus*?

But what I'm really interested in is whether there's a "regular" way of doing this.
Perhaps different ways were idiomatic in different eras.

This is not the same sort of emphasis as moving the adjective to the start of the sentence — that emphasizes the importance of the word, whereas I want to change the meaning of it, make it more extreme.

Answer (score 12):

Using *nimis* (or related words) before an adjective strengthens it, but in a specific direction: *nimis frigidus* is "too cold", not "very cold".
You can also reach a similar tone with comparative: *frigidior* can mean "too cold".

I suggest four ways to emphasize an adjective in the order of my preference:

1. Superlative:
   *Frigidissimus* is a very idiomatic way to say "too cold".
   The absolute superlative (superlative without a comparison to anything else) is common.
   The absolute comparative (see above) is less common.
2. Prefix:
   Many adjectives can be emphasized with a prefix.
   A typical choice for emphasis is *per-*, and it can also be used for verbs.
   This prefix is so common that I would encourage using it productively.
   But for your example this is not needed, since [*perfrigidus*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2043484) is attested in ancient literature.
3. *Valde*:
   *Valde frigidus* is one way to go.
   It should be noticed, though, that *valde* is a contraction from *valide*.
   This gives the word a tone<sup>1</sup> different from the English "very".
   However, *valde* is a good translation of "very".
4. Comparative: The comparative can also be used this way, much like the superlative; [see e.g. A&G](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/comparatives-and-superlatives). In my experience it is rarer than the superlative.

Combining all three suggestions to *valde perfrigidissimus* would sound very overexaggerated.

I am unsure about *multum*.
It sounds less idiomatic to me, but it may turn out to be valid.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Notice that *val(i)de* means also "strongly".
The English "very" is not connected to an adjective like *validus*.
Therefore "very" and *valde* are not exactly alike, but they are very close.