# Superlatives (Cambridge Latin Course)

Tags: adjective, superlatives

I have one question about the translation of the superlatives.

For some reason in *Cambridge Latin Course* they always give the following translation for the superlatives:

> laetissimus — very happy
> iratissimus — very angry

I thought there were two ways to express the superlative in English *happiest* and *most happy*.

Does *very happy* also express the meaning of the superlative? Wouldn't *very happy* be *valde laetus* in Latin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty common for superlatives in Latin to be absolute in the sense that there is no comparison.
The superlative just indicates great extent.
Indeed, *laetissimus* seems to be a more idiomatic choice than *valde laetus* for "very happy".

The Latin relative superlative *laetissimus* can also mean "happiest" in the familiar sense of comparison.
If there is nothing to compare to and "happiest" doesn't make sense, then *laetissimus* is very likely to mean "very happy".

The Latin superlative does not correspond exactly to the English superlative.
Absolute superlatives are a feature that might take some getting used to.
The familiar relative superlative that indicates comparison is not all Latin has to offer.

You may also want to check [this question about different ways to emphasize adjectives](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1285/79) and what [Allen and Greenough have to say about using comparatives and superlatives](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/comparatives-and-superlatives).

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest some Latin grammar workbook where I can read about the absolute superlatives?

Comment: @DachiPachulia Unfortunately I'm not familiar with such grammar workbooks, but perhaps someone else can suggest something. I edited my question to add a link to an online grammar if you want to read some more.